# I have a brand new e bike battery test is good

Tags: power

No power when I connect battery to bike. Battery checked out good. If I put direct power to the bike the screen powers up but nothing to the motor. Any s

Comment: You need to provide much more information.  What brands, what tests have you done, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

If the display lights up, the battery is activated and providing the power. No assist from the engine in this case may be caused by:

- You are in "no assist" mode for some reason. Read the manual how to
  get out of there.
- The battery is so discharged that the engine power
  is suppressed. Try to charge.
- One of the buttons of the engine control panel is stuck in depressed position and the controller operates in some strange way.

If the display does not light up, you may have battery that requires pressing the activation button to turn it on. This button is directly on the battery, try to locate it.

And, of course, something always may be simply damaged.